# Combining Settings and About screens in a mobile web app

Tags: mobile, web-app, settings

To have fewer buttons taking up screen space I'm putting "About" information like version number and whether the app is up to date at the bottom of my Settings screen. I've noticed that the Facebook Messenger Android app does this, but is there a better way than calling the button "Settings"?

Comment: why would you like to change the "Settings" button. I think "Settings" are well known these days, and they do combine About, Settings and more things like Help... If you are trying to save screen real estate use "gear" symbol with an arrow down to show that there are few items in the "Settings"

Comment: I'm just slightly concerned that someone may not realise that version/credits information is under Settings and won't bother to look there. However, I suppose anyone interested in version/credits would be a "power user" who'd have looked in the Settings at least once.

Comment: In this modern world the OS takes care of checking for updates. So there's really no use cases left for displaying such info within the app. If you insist, then the Settings is probably a good place to park them.

Answer (score 1):

Design for 80% of your users in 80% of cases.  It's likely that putting everything under settings will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

it's may be a new idea, what about a mixed symbol ?

maybe, the gear symbol can consist an "i" symbol inside.

Comment: I like that, but what to put as the text?

Comment: i think that symbol would be self-explanatory to power-users.
however, "options" is okay as a short-text.If size permits, "Options & credits" also should do.